# AWS Cloudwatch insight shows no data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I want to build a Logging Dashboard to monitor a application in AWS EC2. So I configure the cloudwatch stuff and everything looks like a charm. But when I go to the cloudwatch logs insights and create a query for the logs, I'm getting 'no data found' for every query/time range I'm using.

I can see there are some logs in the stream when I click on it (in the logs panel) but it cannot discover from insights.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image: This is in the group logs window]

[image: This is the querry with no data]

Maybe someone could help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the query to:

```
fields @logStream, @message | limit 20
```

And expand the time frame to, say, 4 weeks, making sure there are log streams within that time frame that contain log events.

For example:

[image]